# How encode @ symbol while inserting XML documents into marklogic database

Tags: java, xml, marklogic

i am trying to insert below document into marklogic database

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
<Name>Ram</Name>
<Email>ram@ml.com</Email>
</Data>
```

Using marklogic client api version 3.0.5

I got below exception and i didn't find any encoding for @ symbol.

```
 com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: write failed: Bad Request. Server Message: XDMP-DOCSTARTTAGCHAR: Unexpected character "@" in start tag at  line 1
            at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.putPostDocumentImpl(JerseyServices.java:1394)
            at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.putDocument(JerseyServices.java:1196)
            at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.write(DocumentManagerImpl.java:836)
            at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.write(DocumentManagerImpl.java:708)
            at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.write(DocumentManagerImpl.java:638)
```

Comment: You are missing a closing tag `</Email>`. Does this already solve your problem?

Comment: @WagnerMichael  that is a typing mistake i corrected it.

Comment: I have just tried inserting your document with java client api 3.0.5 and MarkLogic 9.8-0 and it worked. Can you go into detail a little more what exactly fails ? Have you tried inserting the document in query console ? Does removing the @ of the email help (just for testing)?

Comment: StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml() i used this method with my data it worked, Thanks
org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils

Comment: I would find it odd if you really needed to escape your xml before feeding it into the ML Client. Can you elaborate how you are reading the XML, and how you pass it into the client? Code snippets are always very much welcomed..